# Не выводится пагинация в Wordpress при использовании ajax-поиска

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Реализовал ajax-поиск, всё работает почти на ура, но не хочет выводиться пагинация.

Нужно выводить именно пагинацию по страницам поиска **site.ru/?s=искомая+фраза**, **site.ru/page/2/?s=искомая+фраза**. То есть по клику на ссылку из пагинации.

Причём, на статической странице пагинация работает корректно.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чём проблема. Буду признателен в помощи.

Код из function.php темы:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_search', 'ajax_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_search', 'ajax_search' );

function ajax_search() {

  $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    's' => $_POST['val'],
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 1)
  );

  if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
      $wp_query->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'loop' );
    }

    pagenavi(); // Вывод пагинации

  } else {
    echo 'Ничего не нашли';
  }

  wp_die();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit','#search',function(e){
  var input = $(this).find('input[name="s"]'),
      val = input.val();

  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: {
        action: 'ajax_search',
        val: val
      },
      success: function(date){
        $('#search-resilt').html(date);
      }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPD 17.02.2017**
Проблема решена заменой кастомной пагинации на стандартную:

```
$val = $_POST['val'];
$paginateArgs = array(
  'base' => '/page/%#%/?s='. $val,
  'current' => '1',
  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
);

echo paginate_links( $paginateArgs );
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `get_query_var()` получает переменные запроса (параметры запроса) из `WP_Query`, который устанавливается в глобальную переменную `$wp_query`.

Вы надеетесь на то, что эта глобальная переменная сохранится при вызове из ajax, а зря. Контекст другой.

Что надо делать:

1. Сохранить запрос WP_Query в параметрах ajax

   ```
   function enq_scripts(){
       $my_args = array(
           'post_type' => 'post', // ну и т.д. - параметры запроса
       );
       $my_query = new WP_Query( $my_args );

       wp_localize_script( 'search', 'ajaxsearch', array(
           'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'search-nonce' ),
           'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
           'query' => $my_query->query,
       ));
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enq_scripts' );
   ```
2. Добавить этот запрос в вызов ajax из скрипта

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
     data: {
       action: 'ajax_search',
       query: ajaxsearch.query,
       val: val
     },
     success: function(date){
       $('#search-resilt').html(date);
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не изменилось. Пагинация не хочет выводиться. Пробовал несколько разных пагинаций.